# Special subscriptions with promotional codes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to have in my app special subscriptions that will be available only for the users with special promotional code (this code is free of charge but you have to obtain it somehow).

Is it possible to create such subscription that could be unlocked only from the app and will not be shown in the iOS subscriptions list?

Comment: No, see 3.1.4 https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#content-codes

Comment: If there is no payment involved through out in whole flow, then it's your wish to enable /disable features in app basis of any code.Like we have membership number in our app which enables user to access some extra features/offers.

Comment: @Paulw11, the thing is I'm using in-app purchase for that. I just want to make this subscription a little special (user has to find promotional code elsewhere to unlock this in-app purchase).